# How to do field completion in FormFunction?

Tags: gui-construction, wolfram-cloud

The control `InputField` has the option `FieldCompletionFunction` for showing optional autocompletions (updates a dropdown as you type).

*Is this possible with cloud-deployed `FormFunction` forms?*

**What I've tried:**

So doing somthing without `FormFunction` like this didn't work:

```
CloudDeploy[
 DynamicModule[{a = "j", q = "", 
   authors = {"Jane Austen", "Jean Rousseau", "Jewel"}, 
   bin = CreateDatabin["quotes"]},
  Panel[Column[{TextGrid[{{"Author", 
        InputField[Dynamic[a], String, 
         FieldCompletionFunction -> (Flatten[
             StringCases[authors, ___ ~~ # ~~ ___, 
              IgnoreCase -> True]] &)]},
       {"QuoteText", 
        InputField[Dynamic[q], String, ImageSize -> {400, 100}]}}, 
      Frame -> None], 
     Button["Add Quote", 
      Echo@ DatabinAdd[bin, {"Author" -> a, "Text" -> q}]]}
    ]]], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

This fails because it seems `FieldCompletionFunction` don't work within `CloudDeploy`:

```
CloudDeploy @ InputField[1, FieldCompletionFunction -> ({"fish", "fowl"} &)]
```

Comment: Just FYI the databin complains about something in the clouddeploy page

Comment: The example isn't functional, I'm just demoing the issue with `FieldCompletionFunction`...